# Equivalent expression in NAND only

Tags: boolean

The problem asks to develop an equivalent expression using only NAND operations, then draw the circuit.

```
AD + BC'D + ACD + BC'
```

I'm still stuck on how to convert this into an expression into NAND. I tried group some out, making it `AD(1 + C) + BC'(D + 1)`, but then it would be a dead-end.

In the sample problem, my teacher gave me, `AB + BC'D + ABD' + BC'`, which I can easily turn it into `AB(1+D’) + BC’(D+1)`, then `AB + BC'` thanks to De Morgan's Laws, then `= ((AB+ BC’)’)’`, and finally `( (AB)’. (BC’)’)’`. All are in “nand” operations. I guess that we can consider “not” is also as a “nand” with one input.

But back again to my main problem, I cannot figure out a way to group anything out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many brackets in a text, I suggest looking at the image:

[Work done in mspaint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PybP8.png)

Hopefully the colors are helpful.

```
AD + BC'D + ACD + BC' =
AD(1+C) + BC'(D+1) = 
AD + BC' = 
((AD + BC')')' = 
((A' + D')(B' + C))' = 
[((A' + D')')' (((B' + C))')']' =  
[(AD)' (BC')']'
```

Comment: Oh lord! I forgot that (1 + anything) should be 1. Thank you so much!